# What causes terminal to enter a loop outputting "? You must enter a valid HighLine::String" after typing in Openshift login in rhc setup?

Tags: installation, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have followed the instructions for setting up Openshift on Mac [here](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/get-started), but when I reach step 2 and write my Openshift login, the terminal enters a loop where it outputs

```
"? You must enter a valid HighLine::String".
```

Does anyone know what that could be about?

EDIT: As requested, here is a copy/paste of the terminal output:

> $ rhc setup
>
> Starting Interactive Setup for OpenShift's command line interface
>
> We'll help get you setup with just a couple of questions. You can skip
>   this in the future by copying your config's around:
>
> ```
> /Users/videre/.openshift/express.conf
> /Users/videre/.ssh/
> ```
>
> To connect to openshift.redhat.com enter your OpenShift login (email
>   or Red Hat login id):

After entering the id, I get an infinite loop of the following:

> ?  You must enter a valid HighLine::String.

In case it is of any use/interest, here is the output when requesting the rhc version:

> $ gem list rhc
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> rhc (0.97.17)

EDIT 2

Highline version:

> $ gem list highline
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> highline (1.6.14, 1.5.0)

Comment: Videre, the output you mentioned is in connection with your OpenShift login?

Comment: Also, please post the version of rhc that you're using (gem list rhc)

Comment: 1. Yes, it is after I enter my OpenShift login and press 'Enter'. I have confirmed that it is the correct login. 2. the rhc version is 0.97.17

Comment: Videre, could you update your question with a copy and paste from the terminal?

Comment: @Paul Morie, I have added a copy/paste from the terminal, is it what you asked for? Thank you for sticking with this, let me know if there is anything else I can do.

Comment: Videre, see Clayton's comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be an old version of highline - can you do 'gem list highline' to see what version you have?

EDIT:
A similar issue as you described was fixed in highline 1.6.8, and this link http://www.dahotre.com/programmings/capistrano-problem-must-enter-valid-highline-string describes a similar problem.

Can you try the following

```
gem install highline --version 1.6.13
gem uninstall highline --version 1.6.14
```

and see if that resolves your issue?

Comment: I have added the highline version to the question. What is highline?

Comment: Videre, highline is a library used by RHC to perform console IO.  See: https://github.com/JEG2/highline

Comment: I installed highline 1.6.13 and uninstalled 1.6.14, and after that it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Someone else has seen this issue with `highline-1.6.14` in another app.

You can try this:

```
gem uninstall highline --version 1.6.14
gem install highline --version 1.6.13
```